# How not to kill a spider while moving out of my flat?

Tags: arthropod

About two weeks ago, when it started getting cold, a house spider (tegenaria domestica I believe) has chosen my flat for spending the winter. I like those spiders so it's not a problem for me. Only problem is, two weeks from now, I'm moving out. I don't know anyone around here who would want to take the spider in.

Would the spider die if I move it back outside now ? In the morning it's around 10°C / 50°F

Since I got a liking to the little guy, is it reasonable to try to take it with me ? There's going to be 5 days between moving out and moving in the new flat, if I go down this road how should I take care of it during those few days ?

What should I do to have the least chances to accidentally kill it ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not that it's absolutely important, but, do you happen to know the species of the spider? Or, it's common name? This may help with environmental conditions & feeding.

Comment: It looks like the standard tegenaria domestica, I'll try to catch a pic this evening but it runs fast.